# How to test the class of elements in a heterogenous array?

Tags: matlab, class, polymorphism, superclass, heterogeneous-array

MATLAB supports grouping objects belonging to subclasses of a common root class implementing [`matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneous-class.html) into a single array, which would have the class of the closest common ancestor, for example:

```
hObj = [ uifigure, uibutton, gobjects(1) ];
K>> class(hObj)
ans =    
    'matlab.graphics.Graphics'
```

I would like to write a function that tests whether the passed-in list of handles of unspecified size (usually a scalar, but possibly an array) belongs to a specific hard-coded class or its descendants.

If the input is a scalar or a homogeneous array (i.e. all objects have the same class), and we are testing for the **target class itself** (not including subclasses), we will get the correct result from a function like this:

```
function tf = isCorrectClass(hCandidate)
  TARGET = 'matlab.ui.Figure';
  tf = isa(hCandidate, TARGET);
end
```

However, this will not work if `hCandidate` is a heterogeneous array, so we must do:

```
function tf = isCorrectClass(hCandidate)
  TARGET = 'matlab.ui.Figure';
  tf = arrayfun(@(x)isa(x, TARGET), hCandidate);
end
```

which works because selecting individual elements from a heterogeneous array makes them revert to their own specific class.

**Question**: How can I adapt the `isCorrectClass` function shown above to the following hierarchy, where the target class is `Middle` (assuming my input array may contain objects of any of the hierarchy's classes)?

```
%                  HierarchyRoot "implements" matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
%                   /        \
%               Middle       LeafD
%             /    |   \ 
%        LeafA   LeafB  LeafC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is using the [relational operators](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html#brkg25s) of [`metaclass`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html) objects:

```
function tf = isCorrectClass(hCandidate)
  TARGET = ?Middle; % Assuming such a class exists
  tf = arrayfun(@(x)metaclass(x) <= TARGET, hCandidate);
end
```

Where:

> *`mc = ?ClassName` returns the `meta.class` object for the class with name, `ClassName`. The `?` operator works only with a class name, not an object.*

and the meaning of `metaclass(x) <= TARGET` is that `x` can either be a subclass or the same class as `TARGET`.